# Is centralizing Android Toolbar a good idea?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, material-design

I'm switching from AcrionBar to Toolbar and I noticed that I need to add Toolbar element in my layout XMLs. My question is that is it a good idea to have toolbar element in a separated XML layout and then include it in all my activity layouts so that I have central and unified way of customizing my toolbar? Also having the java part of setting up of toolbar in a super class of my activities (BaseActivity.java) so I don't have to do it in every single activity?

I thought of this but I wonder if there is any downsides in doing so since I don't have experience with Toolbar.

Any idea will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to implement what I suggested in the question and it turns out that its not possible to centralize it as I suggested because the supper class doesn't have access to the View references in the child class. Even though we can use other tricks to make this work, I noticed that it doesn't worth the effort because the Toolbar car be set as the ActionBar or SupportActionBar variable of the activity and all we need to do is to add Toolbar in all activity layouts

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and use something like this

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
if (mToolbar !=null){
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
}
```

in our activity. After this we can have our code that was working with ActionBar as is (except for some functions that are not available in toolbar like tabs)

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to implement what I suggested in the question and it turns out
>   that its not possible to centralize it as I suggested because the
>   supper class doesn't have access to the View references in the child
>   class.

This is not true. You can extend the setContentView() in the base activity method and inject any view to the children activities.

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) 
{
    DrawerLayout fullView = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_base, null);
    FrameLayout activityContainer = (FrameLayout) fullView.findViewById(R.id.activity_content);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, activityContainer, true);
    super.setContentView(fullView);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (useToolbar()) 
    {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setTitle("Activity Title");
    } 
    else 
    {
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

You can checkout this tutorial on how to implement the Toolbar across all your activities http://mateoj.com/2015/06/21/adding-toolbar-and-navigation-drawer-all-activities-android/